# DataSet with multiple tables

Tags: .net, ado.net

I have a little problem. I don't know how to use the DataSet in VB.NET correctly.

In Visual Studio 2008 I created a DataSet called Network. For the DataSet I took two tables from my database, tServer and tClient. tClient has a foreign key referencing the ID in tServer.

After creating the DataSet I found a new namespace called NetworkTableAdapter which contains the adapter for tServer, tClient and an AdapterManager. There is also a new class called Network, which is the DataSet and contains the DataTables for tServer and tClient.

But how can I fill these DataSet with data and access it? The adapter only have GetData() and Fill() methods, which fill a DataTable, but I want to fill the DataSet.

Sorry for my bad english, I hope that someone understand my problem and can help me. :)

Torben

Comment: I wouldn't worry about your English; it's perfectly understandable.  But more importantly, your question was detailed and specific, and you accept answers to all your questions.  That's better than a lot of people manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as im aware you cant automagically fill a full dataset it this way. Youd have to populate each table in it. To do so, if your using the visual dataset, just right click on the table adapter, and add query. From here you can either add SQL straight into the table adapter, or use a stored procedure.

For the example of a select, the select must match the columns in your dataset.

So if we have a DataTable called CustomersTable, and we have added a func called "GetNewCustomers() you could do CustomersTable dtCustomers = adapter.GetNewCustomers()

See a much better description and tutorials start with #1 and #2 [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/?lang=cs)

Datasets are .NET 2.0 however. I would recommend maybe getting to grips with them and then looking at LINQ2Entities to map your database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I know, that dataset are .NET 2.0, but I have to use .NET 2.0. :) But when I have to fill every table individually, then I don't understand the benefit of this generated dataset class. Apart from this, I don't know how to fill these tables.

Comment: The dataset tables are strongly typed, and can be directly bound to all asp.net data controls.

See the link in my original answer for a better description of how to fill the tables than i could give! Start with tutorial number one.

Answer (score 0):

We fill datasets from stored procedures returning multiple results sets(tables).
    Our wizards At State of Oklahoma agencies did this, I just make boilerplate forms.

1. SP returns 3 results sets:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetAllLists
   AS

   SELECT UserKey, FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName, Suffix, EmailAddress, PeopleSoftID, ChangeDate, ChangeUser
   FROM USERS
   ORDER BY LastName, FirstName

   SELECT a.UserKey, a.DisciplineID, b.Description AS 'DisciplineDescription'
   FROM USER_DISCIPLINES a
   INNER JOIN Discipline b ON a.DisciplineID = b.DisciplineID

   SELECT a.UserKey, a.ApplicationID, b.ApplicationName, a.UserName, a.UserSID, a.UserDomain, a.Active, a.Integrated, a.PositionID, a.ChangeUser, a.ChangeDate
   FROM USER_MAPPINGS a
   INNER JOIN APPLICATION_TABLE b ON a.ApplicationID = b.ApplicationID
   ```
2. clsDataManagement procedure - Partial procedure that does the work

   ```
   Public Shared Function GetInfoInDataset(ByVal StoredProcedureName As String, ByVal DatabaseID As Integer, ByVal ParamArray SQLParams() As SqlClient.SqlParameter) As DataSet
       Dim dsTemp As New DataSet
       Dim cmdSQL As SqlClient.SqlCommand = Nothing
       Dim conSQL As SqlClient.SqlConnection = Nothing
       Dim daSQL As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter = Nothing
       Try
           conSQL = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(BuildConnection(DatabaseID))
           conSQL.Open()
           cmdSQL = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(StoredProcedureName, conSQL)
           cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
           cmdSQL.CommandTimeout = 60
           If Not IsNothing(SQLParams) Then
               For Each p As SqlClient.SqlParameter In SQLParams
                   If Not IsNothing(p) Then
                       If IsNothing(p.Value) Then p.Value = DBNull.Value
                       cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(p)
                   End If
               Next
           End If
           daSQL = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
           daSQL.Fill(dsTemp)
           Return dsTemp
       Catch sqlEx As SqlClient.SqlException
           'MessageBox.Show("A SQL database error occurred preventing PHOCIS from performing the intended function." + Environment.NewLine + "Function was: " + StoredProcedureName + "." + Environment.NewLine + "Error was: " + sqlEx.Message & Environment.NewLine & "Please contact support for assistance.", "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
           MessageBox.Show(sqlEx.Message, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
           'MsgBox("There was an error retrieving the data using procedure " & StoredProcedureName & Environment.NewLine & sqlEx.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error Loading Data")
           Return Nothing
       Catch ex As Exception
           'MessageBox.Show("An error occurred preventing PHOCIS from performing the intended function." + Environment.NewLine + "Function was: " + StoredProcedureName + "." + Environment.NewLine + "Error was: " + ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & "Please contact support for assistance.", "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
           'MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error Loading Data")
           Return Nothing
       Finally
           dsTemp = Nothing
           If Not IsNothing(conSQL) Then conSQL.Close()
           cmdSQL = Nothing
           conSQL = Nothing
           daSQL = Nothing
       End Try
   End Function

   ' Missing lots of overloaded procs with name GetInfoInDataset()
   ```
3. clsData calling procedure:

   ```
   ''' <returns>3 tables,
   ''' 1) OSDH_Apps.USERS 
   ''' 2) OSDH_Apps.USER_DISCIPLINES 
   ''' 3) OSDH_Apps.USER_MAPPINGS </returns>
   Public Function GetAllUserLists() As DataSet
       Try
           Return GetInfoInDataset("GetAllLists")
       Catch ex As Exception
           Return Nothing
       Finally           
       End Try
   End Function

   frmMain.loadstuff()

   Dim userData As DataSet = Nothing
   Dim a As New clsData

   Try
       userData = a.GetAllUserLists
   ```